# How to find if ng-grid row is selected or not using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find the ng-grid cell from the div structure as in the screenshot below,  using the following xpath and clicking on it.

```
"//div[@class='ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope' and contains(text(), 'Stefan')]"
```

This xpath is working, but how do I find if the row is selected before I click on it.

[image]

There is a parent class name that says whether the row is selected or not, and I used the following Xpath's using the parent div,, but it does not seem to work.

```
//div[@class='ui-grid-row ng-scope' and contains(text(), 'Stefan')]

//div[@class='ui-grid-row ng-scope ui-grid-row-selected' and contains(text(), 'Stefan')]
```

Any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: To validate if the element is `selected` or not you have to update the question with the _HTML_ representation of the webelement before and after _selection_.

Comment: my bad, I edited my post to include more info.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Which _Selenium Client_ are you using Java/Python?

Comment: I am using Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the *ng-grid* cell is selected or not you can use the following code block :

```
divClasses = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope' and contains(text(), 'Stefan')]//ancestor::div[@class='ui-grid-row ng-scope']").get_attribute("class")
if "ui-grid-row-selected" in divClasses :
    print("Row is selected")
else :
    print("Row is not selected")
```

Comment: This strategy works... But I had to get the ancestor div and not preceding .. Thanks a ton @DebanjanB